# How to form a sequence of digits of minimum length N satisfying below:

Tags: algorithm

- Any **k** consecutive digits form a unique number
- Any possible number of length **k** can be obtained by choosing **k** consecutive numbers anywhere in sequence

For example, if only `1,2` digits are allowed then using sequence `1 2 2 1 1` any possible 2 digit number can be obtained by choosing any 2 consecutive digits in it as `12` `22` `21` `11`.

How to generalize this to all digits(0-9) and any length **k**

Comment: The Google term you need is "de Bruijn sequence".  Happy hunting :)

Comment: +1 @j_random_hacker for that info. It led me down the Wiki hole hunting linked articles for past 20 min.